# CGAL-bindings compilation

Tags: python-2.7, cgal

I'm trying to install CGAL-binding for Python on Ubuntu 14.
I installed CGAL as at the example in "INSTALL.md" file of CGAL github repository named "how to build the library in Release". As the next step I tried to install  CGAL-binding as Full example https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/wiki/Installation. But

`> cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/usr/local/CGAL -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DPYTHON_OUTDIR_PREFIX=../../examples/python ../..`

`> make -j 4`

causes errors from the [log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B021vhTJWOX4T0lwYnhNY05IZFE).

I didn't change anything in src files, but these errors point to them. How can I fix it?

Comment: what version of CGAL are you using?

Comment: I got it from master branch of GitHub repository. Currently it is CGAL 4.8.900

Comment: I gave it a try and it worked fine on my machine. I suspect you are using some files from another CGAL version. Could you check that some CGAL header from another version are not in the include path?

Comment: I got the same problem trying to install cgal for python 2.7 in windows 10. 
Anyone have some suggestion?